# How to create the logout request in jmeter

Tags: logout

Currently i am using the j meter tool.Login is successfully created.How to create the logout request in j meter tool.Please explain, because i didn't get any link for logout option.

Comment: does your application have logout option?

Answer (score 0):

If your application have logout option then record the same and it will help your users to logout from application

Comment: Yes.I recorded the logout process.but there is no actions are recorded

Comment: just check in developer tool (press f12 while navigating on browser), is there any request is generating while clicking on logout button. If yes, then again try to record or create the request manually